Setup has detected that Setup is currently running
Setup has detected that Setup is currently running. Please close all instances of it now, then click Ok to continue, or Cancel to exit.
Nothing i have tried. so i need to solve it as soon as possible . is there anyone have who can solve it then let me know . and also i am using windows 11 pro

If you encountered this problem during Visual Studio installation, you can try to close all related VS Instances or restart your machine then re-run VS Installer.

Did you encounter this error during the Visual Studio installation?
If so, looks like you're trying to install/update Visual Studio, but another instance of the setup process is already running.
Please check if there are any Visual Studio setup windows open. You can check in Task Manger and find all named vs_installer.exe or similar then close them.
You can also restart your computer and then re-run your VS Installer to see if the issue persists.

I faced the same issue. And easily could resolve it once i close the VScode and restart it.

The tags suggest that this problem occurred with Visual Studio rather than Visual Studio Code. The question does not enlighten the reader as to whether Visual Studio was running at the time when the problem occurred, or what exactly the asker was aiming to do .
